# Playframework2.4 の Form で list(number) をバインドした時のフィールドコンストラクタ挙動で、value 値が取得できない。

Tags: scala, playframework

環境 :
 - Playframework 2.4.2

実現したい事：

- マルチセレクトのチェックボックスを、Play 標準の helper のように定義したい。
- 動作仕様として下記のように使いたい

  @myhelper.multipleCheckBox(c("multiSelect"), Map("first" -> "1", "second" -> "2", "third" -> "3"))

作成したコード：

```
(field: play.api.data.Field, keyValues: Map[String, String])(implicit messages: play.api.i18n.Messages)
@helper.input(field) { (id, name, value, htmlArgs) =>

  @{value.toString}
  @{value.getClass.toString}

  @defining(keyValues.toList.zipWithIndex){ results =>
    @for(kv_i <- results){
    <label class="checkbox-inline">
        <input id="@{id}_@{kv_i._2}" name="@{name}[@{kv_i._2}]" type="checkbox"
            value="@{kv_i._1._2}" @if(value.exists(v => {keyValues.exists(_._2 == v)})){checked="true"}> @kv_i._1._1
    </label>
    }
  }
}
```

問題点：

- バインドした際に、「selected」属性がつかない。

  val checkBoxes = Form(single("multiSelect" -> list(longNumber)))
  val test = checkBoxes.bind(Map("multiSelect[0]" -> "2"))
  println(test.value) // Some(List(2)) が表示
  println(test("multiSelect"))
  // 下記が出力(Form には value 値があるものの、Field にはない)
  // Field(Form(play.api.data.ObjectMapping1@58b5f405,Map(multiSelect[0] -> 2),List(),Some(List(2))),multiSelect,List(),None,List(),None)

  しかし、この form を画面テンプレートに送っても、value 値は「None class scala.None$」の表示。

そもそも target にバインドされた時の型が Option[List[String]] や、Option[List[Long]] のような気がしないでもないので、target に値が入っても上記コードで出ない気はしますが、そもそも target が None のままで困っています。
これは自分のコード上のミスなのか、仕様なのかバグなのか…それすらわからない状況なので、知っている方是非ご教授下さい。

尚、レンダリング時は、下記の様な html が吐かれていて、チェックした時にサーバでバインド→値の取得はできています。

```
<div class="col-sm-10">
    None
    class scala.None$
    <label class="checkbox-inline">
        <input id="multiSelect_0" name="multiSelect[0]" type="checkbox" value="1"> first
    </label>
    <label class="checkbox-inline">
        <input id="multiSelect_1" name="multiSelect[1]" type="checkbox" value="2"> second
    </label>
    <label class="checkbox-inline">
        <input id="multiSelect_2" name="multiSelect[2]" type="checkbox" value="3"> third
    </label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[select.html.scala](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/master/framework/src/play/src/main/scala/views/helper/select.scala.html) の実装が参考になります。

List 値を含む Field の場合、 [Field#indexes](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/master/framework/src/play/src/main/scala/views/helper/select.scala.html) で値が定義されているインデックス一覧を得ることができます。 [Field#apply](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/api/scala/index.html#play.api.data.Field@apply(key:String):play.api.data.Field) を使うと相対的な指定で Field が取得できます。渡されてくる Field は、今回の場合 `"multiSelect"` のキーを含みますので、`"[0]"` などのインデックスを付与して、`"multiSelect[0]"` などの Field にアクセスします。値は `"multiSelect[0]"` などが持つため、これを比較対象として用います。

また Map は順序を保持しないため keyValues は `Seq[(String, String)]` などのほうがよいでしょう。

次のような感じになると思います。

```
@(field: play.api.data.Field, keyValues: Seq[(String, String)])(implicit messages: play.api.i18n.Messages)
@helper.input(field) { (id, name, value, htmlArgs) =>
    @defining(field.indexes.flatMap(i => field(s"[$i]").value).toSet) { values =>
        @keyValues.zipWithIndex.map { case ((k, v), idx) =>
            <label class="checkbox-inline">
                <input id="@{id}_@{idx}" name="@{name}[@{idx}]" type="checkbox"
                value="@{v}" @if(values(idx.toString)){checked}> @k
            </label>
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: ご協力ありがとうございます。
とても参考になりました。

Field#indexes なんてものがあったのですね…。

記述いただきましたコードも、ほとんどそのまま実行できました、
`@if(values(idx.toString))` だけ判定を `values.contains(v)` に置き換えてます。

Comment: なお `Set#contains()` と `Set#apply()` は両方共に要素が含まれているかを返します。`values.contains(v)` は `values.apply(v)` や `values(v)` とも書けます。